# PHP/MySQL select from with multiple WHERE and ranges

Tags: php, mysql

Here is exactly what I would like to do (step by step in the order it makes sense to me)

1. SELECT FROM table
2. WHERE x is within +/- 6 from variable $x
3. AND WHERE y is within +/- 6 from variable $y
4. And hopefully have it all returned in a neatly organized array..

Is this possible? Not really looking to get it handed to me, more looking for a starting point to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is your answer.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x BETWEEN $x-6 AND $x+6 AND y BETWEEN $y-6 AND $y+6
```

Put in a `mysqli_query` (or use `PDO`) and fetch the results.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped out a ton!

Answer (score 0):

you can only one where clause in one select statement

but you can you multiple comparator like

```
select * from table where (col1=10 and column2>25)  or col3=10
```

for your above query it

```
select * from table where (x>-6 and x<6) and  (x>-6 and x<6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE x >= $x - 6 AND x <= $x + 6
AND y >= $y - 6 AND y <= $y + 6
```

Then use PHP's functions to `fetch_array` on the query